# Next-Auth and Firebase 9 Rules do not return authenticated user

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, next.js

I am building social media app using Next.js and I am trying to implement some security logic in Firebase 9 Rules. I also use firebase-adapter for next-auth. The problem is that whenever I want to use my function

```
function isAuth() {
  return request.auth != null;
}
```

it always returns null value, even though I am logged in. What's more, on every page I fetch the session using getServerSideProps. Maybe that should be the problem? If yes, how could I solve this without changing SSR?

Comment: It seems Firebase auth has not loaded user yet. Does the query work when made after the page is rendered?

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working. I also tried to logout and sign in and I am still not capable of reading the posts. Here is the rule `match /posts/{postId} {
     allow write: if true;
      allow read: if isAuth();
    }`
Of course if I negate this expression then I can see the posts, so I think it's correctly structured.